# Code hard to read with answer's Green Background

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, usability, design

I don't want to sound like a little princes lol, but sometimes I have a hard time reading C# code with a green background, the classes, methods and variables syntax highlighting is green too (although a different shade of green), but it still sort of blends in with the background. Maybe making the background even paler would work?

Thanks!

Comment: So you're saying the current background color makes it hard to see sharp? ;)

Comment: Puns f-ing rock!!

Comment: Hey, could you please link to the offending code?

Comment: Here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307353/linq-many-to-many-left-join-grouping/1307492#1307492

Comment: I guess I see what you mean.  But, I don't think it's that bad.

Comment: I second the request, as for many people from a certain age (usually 40+), distinguishing shades of the same color becomes more and more difficult. This is especially true for shades of blue, but holds for other colors too.

Comment: Maybe there should be an "I am colourblind" user preference that switches to a high-contrast stylesheet? (or even a choice of stylesheets, for different kinds of colourblindness)

Comment: Looks like this got taken care of. Now there's no background for correct answers, only a green check mark.

Comment: I really like the suggestion of optional stylesheets to handle colourblindness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We no longer use the green background to denote accepted answer; the green checkmark suffices.

Comment: But it's not blinking!

Answer (score 1):

You might try using the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108) extension if you're using Firefox; it allows you to restyle existing pages exactly the way you want.

For example, you could write a rule that looks like this:

```
.accepted-answer code {
   background-color: white !important;
}
```