# What's the advantage of removing the accepted answer green background?

Tags: feature-request, answers, design, accepted-answer

I always found it really easy to know if the question was solved or still pending simply by the green background. Now that its removed I have to consciously search for that little green arrow to know the same. Whats the advantage of removing the green background? Can we get it back?

Comment: They got rid of it due to all the moderator flags from users complaining that the green clashed with their outfits.

Comment: Vote here to bring it back: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22510/please-bring-back-shading-to-accepted-answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They reduced the number of colors on the system to help out with color selection for the Stack Exchange sites.

[Help StackExchange With Colors](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/help-stackexchange-with-colors/)

> We’ve been creeping further and
> further towards the refuge of
> minimalism in our Trilogy layouts over
> the last year. fact, I just deployed a
> change to remove the accepted answer
> color to make color schemes a bit
> easier for SE.

Comment: It's a shame they removed the nice subtle green backgrund but kept the awful dark shades that appear (and fade after a few seconds) when you post an answer. It makes your answer unreadable for a short while.

Comment: And, as Jeff writes in October 2009, in [Code hard to read with answer's Green Background](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15722/code-hard-to-read-with-answers-green-background/27206#27206): *"We no longer use the green background to denote accepted answer; the green checkmark suffices."*

Answer (score 3):

You're only having to consciously search for the green arrow because your brain learned to "read" the site one way. Give it time, it'll learn to notice the green arrow much more quickly.

Comment: A huge green flag is easier to read than a tiny green dot.

Comment: @Jeremy true, but the "background process" of my brain notes which users are moderators when I'm browsing through this list of answers even though it's just a tiny diamond. I don't have to look for it.

Comment: oh... that's what the diamond is for... I learned something new today

Comment: I find that the check mark is too similar to the down arrow that it's immediately under, so the two seem to blend together.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any advantage whatsoever in the change. All I can really say is that perhaps they made the change so that it didn't stand out TOO much and then potentially cause users to ignore all the rest of the answers that may be provided, regardless of how good they might be.

Answer (score 3):

[Colors are hard](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/help-stackexchange-with-colors/). Perhaps they <strike>went shopping</strike> decided to reduce the number required?

Answer (score 1):

One (admittedly small) advantage is what Diago [mentioned here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22510/why-dont-accepted-answers-show-shading-anymore/22524#22524):

> It does make answers easier to read,
>   and helps on sites like SF or SU where
>   we use screenshots on white
>   backgrounds.

(E.g. [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/32885/what-do-you-have-for-a-home-server-for-multimedia/32940#32940) looks way better after the change.)

Comment: Of course, it **mocks** the time i spent making transparent backgrounds for *my* screenshots...

Comment: Heh, true. :) But oftentimes it is quite reasonable to use existing images, which might have white background (like the ones from Apple in my example)