# As OP cannot accept own answer before 2 days have passed. Should OP posts stand out more?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

[Automated testing against third party library that maintains a singleton state internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776485/automated-testing-against-third-party-library-that-maintains-a-singleton-state-i/8776870#8776870)

Althought not a perfect solution, I tried accepting my post as answer. But I got a message saying that it couldn't be accepted until 2 days.

Are we assuming that everybody will notice that the answer was written by me (the OP) and thus instantly separating it from a rejected answer? 
I didn't know about the "2 day rule". Therefore, if I stumbled across this thread, I would be in danger of assuming that the problem was not solved.

---

In this particular case, however, I *would* like to hear from more people, so it doesn't really bother me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It already does, as the user card has a different background color:

[image: User card background color]

(A long time ago, the whole post used to have a blue background color, just like accepted answers [used to be greenish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23881/whats-the-advantage-of-removing-the-accepted-answer-green-background/23886#23886). See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean)

Comment: As you didn't notice, *maybe* your feature request still stands?

Comment: You're correct; OP answers used to have a blue background a long time ago.